# SCSS/CSS Using :not selector for only certain elements

Tags: css, sass

I have a common element which contains articles, and want to treat all but the first child differently as follows:

```
.listing{

    article{

        // Some styles
    }

    article:not(:first-child){

       // Some more styles

    }

}
```

All well and good. However on some listings they should all be treated the same, so I don't want to include the article:not(:first-child) selector, it needs to be like the following:

```
.listing.alt{
    article{
         // Some styles
         // Some more styles
    }
}
```

How can I combine these two rules without repeating everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I think I've figured it out using Sass:

```
.listing{

     article{
          // Generic Styles
     }

    &.alt article,
    &:not(.alt) article:not(:first-child){

       // More Styles

    }
}
```

I also see that my original code example was a bit weird so I've updated it so it's a bit more correct.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="listing">
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
</div>
<div class="listing alt">
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listing:not(.alt) article:not(:first-child) {color:gainsboro;}
```

[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/too5og3t/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I specifically want to apply styles to all articles except the first one. In your example I would need to counter all the styles for the first-child that I apply for the generic article. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I see that I misunderstood something. Will this help? `.listing:not(.alt) article:not(:first-child) {color:gainsboro;}`

Comment: Thanks again, I eventually came up with the same thing. All sorted!